# Sql update issue

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I can't figure out why this isn't working?!

```
        protected void Submit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Update();
    }

    public void Update()
    {
        try
        {
            using (SqlConnection conn =
                new SqlConnection(conStr))
            {
                conn.Open();
                using (SqlCommand cmd =
                    new SqlCommand("UPDATE DriverInfo SET FirstName=@NewFirstName, LastName=@NewLastName, Age=@NewAge, Country=@NewCountry, Town=@NewTown WHERE UserId=@Id", conn))
                {
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Id", currentUserId);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NewFirstName", tbfirstname.Text);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NewLastName", tblastname.Text);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NewAge", tbage.Text);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NewCountry", tbcountry.Text);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NewTown", tbtown.Text);

                    int rows = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                    //rows number of record got updated
                }
            }
        }
        catch (SqlException ex)
        {
            //Log exception
            //Display Error message
        }
    }
```

This should be a page where the logged in user can change his settings and them should be updated in the database.

Comment: there is no error except that the database isn't getting updated. I know that the connection is working cause i've used the same connection string for many other functions.

Comment: What's is the value of 'rows' after cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() has been executed?

Comment: currentUserId = (Guid)currentUser.ProviderUserKey;

Comment: when debuggin gcheck the value of Id

Comment: Also, check to see if the table is owned by DBO or another user.   If it is owned by dbo, make the table name in the query  dbo.driverinfo.  SQL server allows the same table name with different owners

Comment: check you CurrentUserID value. may be it is 0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only thing that I can see from the code given and with no exceptions is that the `@Id` may not be set right or not be equal to any existing Id's in the current table.

Comment: Works like a charm now, the guid was set to null exactly as you though. thanks.

Comment: parek no problem good luck in further endeavors